# Codable for API request

Tags: ios, swift, codable

How would I make this same API request through codables?
In my app, this function is repeated in every view that makes API calls.

```
func getOrders() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let spinningHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            spinningHUD.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

            let returnAccessToken: String? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "accessToken") as? String

            let access  = returnAccessToken!
            let headers = [
                "postman-token": "dded3e97-77a5-5632-93b7-dec77d26ba99",
                "Authorization": "JWT \(access)"
            ]

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://somelink.com")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)

            request.httpMethod          = "GET"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

            let session  = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error!)

                } else {
                    if let dataNew = data, let responseString = String(data: dataNew, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print("----- Orders -----")
                        print(responseString)
                        print("----------")

                        let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString)
                        print(dict?["results"] as Any)
                        guard let results = dict?["results"] as? NSArray else { return }
                        self.responseArray = (results) as! [HomeVCDataSource.JSONDictionary]

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            spinningHUD.hide(animated: true)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }

                }

            })

            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the JSON response that you want to parse using `Codable`.

Comment: You need to implement `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` and `convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` in your models and then you can do something like `var arrayOfComments : [CommentModel] = try JSONDecoder().decode([CommentModel].self, from: response.result.value!)`

Comment: Info: You can use background thread for network request. Main thread for update UI

Comment: @ReinierMelian Will you elaborate more please?

Comment: Paste your JSON response on this site you will get Codable data https://www.json4swift.com/

Comment: The question cannot be reasonably answered without knowing the JSON. And please don't use `NSMutable...` classes if there is a native counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do the following

1. Create Base Service as below

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

enum MethodType: String {
    case get     = "GET"
    case post    = "POST"
    case put     = "PUT"
    case patch   = "PATCH"
    case delete  = "DELETE"
}

class BaseService {

    var session: URLSession!

    // MARK: Rebuilt Methods
    func FireGenericRequest<ResponseModel: Codable>(url: String, methodType: MethodType, headers: [String: String]?, completion: @escaping ((ResponseModel?) -> Void)) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        // Request Preparation
        guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Error Building URL Object")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
        request.httpMethod = methodType.rawValue

        // Header Preparation
        if let header = headers {
            for (key, value) in header {
                request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
            }
        }

        // Firing the request
        session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    guard let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self , from: data) else {
                        print("Error Decoding Response Model Object")
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(object)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    private func buildGenericParameterFrom<RequestModel: Codable>(model: RequestModel?) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
        var object: [String : AnyObject] = [String : AnyObject]()
        do {
            if let dataFromObject = try? JSONEncoder().encode(model) {
                object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataFromObject, options: []) as! [String : AnyObject]
            }
        } catch (let error) {
            print("\nError Encoding Parameter Model Object \n \(error.localizedDescription)\n")
        }
        return object
    }

}
```

the above class you may reuse it in different scenarios adding request object to it and passing any class you would like as long as you are conforming to Coddle protocol

2. Create Model Conforming to Coddle protocol

```
class ExampleModel: Codable {
    var commentId : String?
    var content : String?

    //if your JSON keys are different than your property name
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case commentId = "CommentId" 
        case content = "Content"
    }

}
```

3. Create Service to the specific model with the endpoint constants subclassing to BaseService as below

```
class ExampleModelService: BaseService<ExampleModel/* or [ExampleModel]*/> {

    func GetExampleModelList(completion: ((ExampleModel?)/* or [ExampleModel]*/ -> Void)?) {
        super.FireRequestWithURLSession(url: /* url here */, methodType: /* method type here */, headers: /* headers here */) { (responseModel) in
            completion?(responseModel)
        }
    }

}
```

- Usage

```
class MyLocationsController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    // better to have in base class for the controller
    var exampleModelService: ExampleModelService = ExampleModelService()

    // MARK: Life Cycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        exampleModelService.GetExampleModelList(completion: { [weak self] (response) in
            // model available here
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to conform `Codable` protocol in your model classes, for this you need to implement 2 methods, one for code your model and another for decode your model from `JSON`

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws

required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
```

After that you will be able to use `JSONDecoder` class provided by apple to decode your JSON, and return an array (if were the case) or an object of your model class.

```
class ExampleModel: Codable {
    var commentId : String?
    var content : String?

    //if your JSON keys are different than your property name
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case commentId = "CommentId" 
        case content = "Content"
    }

}
```

Then using `JSONDecoder` you can get your model array like this

```
do {
    var arrayOfOrders : [ExampleModel] = try JSONDecoder().decode([ExampleModel].self, from: dataNew)                           
    }
    catch {
    }
```

Comment: Basically you don't **need** to implement the protocol methods. In the default implementation the methods are synthesized. And the object conforming to `Codable` is not required to be a class nor to inherit from `NSObject`. And why are the properties declared as optional?

Comment: @vadian you are right, but if you want to have different property names than JSON definition you need to define `CodingKeys`, and implement method protocols or Iam wrong about this?, about NSObject you are totally right, i will remove that, thanks

Comment: Adding `CodingKeys` does not require to implement the protocol methods.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can recommend you to use this application -quicktype- for turning json file to class or struct (codable) whatever you want. [enter link description here](https://quicktype.io/).

After that you can create a generic function to get any kind of codable class and return that as a response.

```
func taskHandler<T:Codable>(type: T.Type, useCache: Bool, urlRequest: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error : \(error)")
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let dataDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(dataDecoded))
                // if says use cache, let's store response data to cache
                if useCache {
                    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                        self.storeDataToCache(urlResponse: response, urlRequest: urlRequest, data: data)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        } else {
            completion(.failure(SomeError))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```